# Naming a Django Model after the User's name it is extending

Tags: python, django

In my models I have:

```
    class Collaborator(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name= 'fotografia', upload_to='collaborators')
```

According to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) this is the correct way to extend a user object, but I couldn't find a reference on how to name this "collaborator" after the user.

I'm referring to the Django Admin Interface where creating a Collaborator will result in a object named "Collaborator object". Is there any way for the Collaborator to appear with the user's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a `__str__` method, like explained in [Models Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__):

```
class Collaborator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name= 'fotografia', upload_to='collaborators')

    def __str__(self):

        return self.user.first_name #or whatever else you want.
```

Comment: Learning Django and forgetting basic Python/Object Programming. Thank you!